# UnsatisfiedLinkError: Operation not permitted Issue in Marshmallow

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have an Android application where I am loading a shared object using System.loadLibrary("full file path"). This was working fine till I was using API 19.

However since I have updated my device to API 23 the same application is unable to load the shared object:

Full error is:

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: couldn't map "<Shared Object Path>" segment 2: Operation not permitted`.

I am using Android Studio.
NDK-11 for building the shared Object

Comment: Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app.

If your target sdk is 23, you should check if requesting permission at runtime fixes it.

Comment: Even after providing run time permission, I am not able to load the Shared Objects. I am able to read/write normal files(txt etc), but loading SO is giving issue. A workaround I found is to copy SO in local Application directory and load it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Check this temp solution for Android 6.x devices:

**build.gradle**

```
android
        {

            //23 or higher
            compileSdkVersion 23
            buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"


 defaultConfig
                    {
                        ...
                        //important code, write API 22
                        targetSdkVersion 22
                       ...
                    }

...
}
```

Comment: This did helped(to avoid dynamic permission issue), however I still have to copy my shared object in local application directory before loading it.